# what means "It is so fine a gift"

Tags: sentence-meaning

I heard this sentence in a video.What actually means by "so fine a gift".I didn't understand.Please explain what kind of sentence is this?

Comment: Can you share the video with us?

Comment: https://youtu.be/80MZos91Z8I

Comment: Compare *It is so fine a gift* to *You are so kind,* where you can think of ***so*** as being equivalent to ***very***. It's just that in your example it's not idiomatic to simply make that substitution because we also need to tweak the word order: *It is **a very fine** gift.*

Comment: Thanks for the answer but one thing is why the article " a " is after the adjective?

Comment: So fine a gift, so tall a man, so small a child, so fat a pig, so hot a day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what *Practical English Usage* says about this construction (Unit 187):

> After *as*, *how*, *so*, *too* and *this/that* meaning *so*, adjectives go before *a/an*. This structure is common in a formal style.
>
> > *as/how/so/too/this/that* + adjective + *a/an* + noun
> >
> > *I have **as good a voice** as you.
> >
> >     She is **too polite a person** to refuse.
> >
> >     **How good a pianist** is he?
> >
> >     I couldn't afford **that big a car**.
> >
> >     It was **so warm a day** that I could hardly work.*
>
> The structure is not possible without *a/an*.
>
> > *I like your country – it's so beautiful.* (not <s>*I like your so beautiful country.*</s>)
> >     *Those girls are too kind to refuse.* (not <s>*They are too kind girls to refuse.*</s>)

If you wanted to put *a* in front of the adjective, you'd have to use *such*. Unit 597.1:

> We use *such* before a noun (with or without an adjective).
>
> > *They’re **such fools**.* (not <s>*They’re so fools.*</s>)
> >     *It was **such good milk** that we couldn't stop drinking it.* (not <s>*It was so good milk that...*</s>)
>
> *Such* comes before *a/an*.
>
> > *She's **such a** baby.*
> >     *I've never met **such a** nice person.* (not <s>*...a such/so nice person.*</s>)

Note also that you can use *so* in front of an adjective alone. Unit 597.2:

> We use *so* before an adjective alone (without a noun) or an adverb.
>
> > *She's **so babyish**.* (not <s>*She's such babyish.*</s>)
> >     *The milk was **so good** that we couldn't stop drinking it.*
> >     *Why do you talk **so slowly**?*

That said, here is how you could phrase your example:

> It is **so fine a** gift.
>   It is **such a fine** gift.
>   This gift is **so fine**.

The second and third examples are the most neutral and common, in my opinion. As *PEU* says, *so + adjective + noun* is more common in a formal style.